# How to access a parents child. getChildat(d).(the movieclip inside the child)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
        for (var c:int = 0; c < childrenOnStage; c++)
        {
            if (getChildAt(c).name == "player")
            {

                for (var d:int = 0; d < childrenOnStage; d++)
                {
                    if (getChildAt(d).name == "ground")
                    {
                        if (getChildAt(d).level1Ground.hitTestPoint(getChildAt(c).x + 13, getChildAt(c).y, true))
```

Good Morning friends and strangers.

I am trying to access a movieclip inside another movie clip. level1Ground is an instance name I am trying to reach out to this but I can't.

```
 1119: Access of possibly undefined property level1Ground through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

Should I not use this method of getChildAt or will there be a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean 'inside another movieclip'?  Have you made one movieclip a child of the other? You might show a little more code.

Answer (score 0):

```
(getChildAt(d) as MovieClip).level1Ground/*...*/
```

Doing this will cast the return from the `getChildAt()` as a `MovieClip` and then you can access to inner movieclip.